# JavaFX WARNING: System can't support ConditionalFeature.SCENE3D

Tags: java, linux, nvidia, javafx-8, linux-mint

I have a Samsung laptop which has Nvidia GeForce GT 650M graphics card with Linux Mint Qiana and proprietary drivers installed. I am sure about 3D support because I can play 3D games without problem. I am on a project and I used JavaFX 3D shapes. Even if I run project with optirun command (since my graphic card is an optimus) it keeps giving

```
javafx.scene.paint.Material <init>
WARNING: System can't support ConditionalFeature.SCENE3D
```

Also I tried with Windows on the same machine and it works normally. Am I doing something wrong or is the problem between javafx and linux?

Answer (score 0):

For Windows 7 in Nvidia Control Panel you can adjust the graphics processor in use either globally or for specific programs like cmd.exe or java.exe.
At the start button type cmd.exe or java.exe and in the context menu select "Run with graphics processer" "Nvidia processor".

Comment: I don't have any problem about Windows 7. My problem is about Linux Mint.